# NFSv4 Symbolic link under virtual root

Tags: symbolic-link, nfs4

My intention:

1. use `/exports` as my virtual root of NFSv4
2. export dir `/my/dir` through NFS

So I created a symlink under `/exports` like this

```
# ln -s /my/dir /exports/dir
```

and my /etc/exports looks like:

```
/exports *(async,rw,fsid=0,no_root_squash,insecure,no_subtree_check,crossmnt)
```

When I mount from client using:

```
# mount -t nfs4 192.168.1.52:/dir /mnt
```

I got following error message:

> mount.nfs4: mounting 192.168.1.52:/dir failed, reason given by server:
>         No such file or directory

According to [this](http://nfsv4.bullopensource.org/doc/NFS3_NFS4_migration.pdf) it should work. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You need to mount

```
 mount -t nfs4 192.168.1.52:/export/dir /mnt
```

Edit: Strike that - it's my daily NFSv3 practice shining through (and missing the crucial `v4` part in the question).

Try to remove the link and bind the dir instead:

```
mkdir /exports/dir
mount --bind /my/dir /exports/dir
```

and if it works, add the mount to `/etc/fstab`.

```
 /my/dir  /exports/dir   none    bind  0  0
```

Restart NFS server

If this still fails, try to make `/exports/dir` an explicit line it `/etc/exports`.

Comment: Sorry that's NFSv3 way of doing it. BTW, I have another dir which is under /exports and not a symbolic link works as expected. So I'm fairly sure it's about the the symbolic link.

Comment: @AndySong: See my edit, maybe this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm sure that works. Only that when I do 'df' it'll show a bunch of mounts that I don't want to see otherwise. A little annoying.